# Serverless Packaging for combining multiple folders

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, packaging, serverless

Using the Serverless v1.26 with Python and trying to create a deployment package that AWS Lambda would allow me to import Python modules. As I figured so far, Lambda wants you to put all the python files in the zip without any folder structure. No matter what I do Serverless always package them with folders and causing issues on Lambda side.
I want to put individual files from my custom functions folder paired with common functions in each package. And yes I have enabled the "individually:true" globally.

I'm struggling with this problem for days, my current project folder structure is like this:

```
src
|_ common-functions
|   |_ common_function.py
|   |_ another_common_function.py
|
|_ custom-functions
    |_ custom_function.py
    |_ another_custom_function.py
```

and I want my deployment package to be with the following structure:

```
src.zip
|_ common_function.py
|_ another_common_function.py
|_ custom_function.py
```

but it always end up like this:

```
src.zip
    |_ common-functions
    |   |_ common_function.py
    |   |_ another_common_function.py
    |
    |_ custom-functions
        |_ custom_function.py
```

Could anyone help me with this maybe? No matter what I tried it always puts them individually including their folders.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to do that in serverless.yml file?  for example `include` and `exclude` options?

Comment: yes i did, when i use include it still puts each python file under separate folders instead of putting all of them under the root folder